# Re-map Alt+drag in Unity. I need it for Inkscape

Tags: 12.10, unity, shortcut-keys, inkscape

I need Alt+drag for some of Inkscape function, instead of just draggin my current window, how do I re-map "drag window" key to another shorcut?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me its related to compiz, not Unity.
However, install compizconfig:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

then launch it and search "move window", you'll find the shortkey `alt<button1>` and change it.